# deja de funcionar npm

Tags: nodejs, npm, terminal

Tenemos el proyecto en gitlab y después de cambiar la rama en que trabajaba antes me dejó de funcionar npm y cuando intento de instalarlo de nuevo me sale este:

> up to date, audited 1 package in 364ms
>
> found 0 vulnerabilities

Y cuando le doy npm start este:

> npm ERR! missing script: start
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/kateskripnikova/.npm/_logs/2021-04-21T05_15_55_632Z-debug.log

No entiendo cómo arreglarlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

has intentado revisar si tienes las dependencias instaladas, por lo cual te recomendaría revisar eso, de lo contrario te recomiendo usar npm i -D
la D es para indicar si es para desarrollo, de lo contrario solo dejalo ahí sin -D

Comment: Pues he intentado y con -D y sin, sale lo mismo :(   up to date, audited 1 package in 220ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: De casualidad hiciste un merge desde la rama con la cual trabajabas antes hacia la nueva?

Comment: De verdad no sé. Me lo hizo mi compañero

Answer (score 0):

El error

```
npm ERR! missing script: start
```

se muestra cuando npm no encuentra qué empezar. Esto ocurre porque

- no encuentra en la raíz del proyecto un fichero `server.js`
- no has definido en el fichero de configuración `package.json` cuál es el fichero con el código para iniciar tu aplicación, algo como:

```json
"main": "index.js",
```

- no tienes ningún script con el nombre start:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start": "node index.js"
},
```